# jQuery populate form plugin and json square bracket issue

Tags: jquery, json

I have a node server returning a json string which contains an array:

```
{
  "title": "Hello",
  "categories": [ "5033e22163bc849f5a000003"]
}
```

The data is sent with json headers and has also been checked with a json validator. The jquery populate plugin site has basically the same example. However this trows an error when I try to populate my form with:

```
$.getJSON("/api/products/8123h123123123", function(data) {
      $('#productEditForm').populate(data);
})
```

The error in my safari console:

```
jquery-1.7.2.min.js:3  Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: ]
```

I have tried changing my json to:

```
{
  "title": "Hello",
  "categories": [ {0: "5033e22163bc849f5a000003"}]
}
```

But the plugin does not recognize it nor is it the same as the data I get when I serialize my form.

How to get rid of this error?

Comment: Try removing the trailing comma

Comment: Not the issue - forgot to clean my sample for posting. Just edited. Thanks.

Comment: You might try using the unminified version of jQuery during testing to see if you can narrow down the problem. It might not be complaining about your json string, it could be a bug in the plugin or an error somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Ha. Turns out the issue was that my multiple select I was trying to populate needed square brackets - so the original JSON data is fine. The populate plugin threw up when not finding the brackets.